# AngularJS $http.get in MVC5 Areas

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an Area named Employer in MVC5 and in the root a folder named app that contains a folder named list. In list folder I created js files and as a service factory I user this code :

```
    angSalaryApp.factory('listService', ["$http",
  function ($http) {
      return {
          newList: newList
      };

      function newList() {
          return $http.get("Areas/Employer/List/newlist");
      }

      return {
          userLists: userLists
      };

      function userLists() {
          return $http.get("Areas/Employer/List/getlists");
      }
  }
]);
```

but newlist and userlists actions aren't called and my controller variables are undefined. it's my controller code :

```
angSalaryApp.controller('listController',
    function ListController($scope, listService) {
        $scope.list = listService.newList;

        $scope.userlist = [];

        $scope.count = 0;

        $scope.submitForm = function () {

        };

        $scope.loadLists = function () {
            $scope.userlist = listService.userLists;
            $scope.d = "ffdgdfg";
        };

        $scope.updateName = function (newtitle) {
            $scope.list.Name = newtitle;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your factory like this:

```
angSalaryApp.factory('listService', ["$http",
  function ($http) {
      return {
          newList: newList,
          userLists: userLists
      };

      function newList() {
          return $http.get("Areas/Employer/List/newlist");
      }

      function userLists() {
          return $http.get("Areas/Employer/List/getlists");
      }
   }
]);
```

...otherwise userLists will be private.

Comment: Why my action isn't called?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "actions", but both your service methods are returning promises from $http. You probably need to resolve those using "then".

Comment: I need to call Areas/Employer/List/newlist that is a method in ListController in MVC5 application.

Comment: Ok, now I am following along... :-)

Comment: You need to use paths that starts with "/" i.e. your application root.

Comment: Instead of this:
    $http.get("Areas/Employer/List/newlist")
use this:
    $http.get("**/Areas/Employer/List/newlist**")

Comment: I did this. but nothing get.

Comment: Have you had a look at the traffic in Fiddler? What does the response look like from the MVC action?

Comment: Any solution in sight? Have you ensured that the routing is correct and that you can reach the action/endpoint?

Comment: it's my routing
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");    
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "account/login/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "account", action = "login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "" });
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Default_Employer",url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Employer" });

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the route initialization to the Area registration?

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyAreaTest
{
    public class MyAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get { return "MyArea"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Area_default",
                "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a new project without area and default settings and nothing changed.